# undefined method `alias_method_chain' after upgrading rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just updated my rails from 4.2 to 5.1.4, I successfully update the rails version and gem dependencies but after running server I am getting following error.

```
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activeadmin'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `alias_method_chain' for  #<Class:ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency>
Did you mean?  alias_method
```

Any body help me what I am missing here and why I am getting this error.

Comment: Point the active admin gem in gemfile to master branch and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Its still not working :(

Comment: Did you use devise with active admin then point it to the master branch too.

Comment: Please post your Gemfile and also a stack trace of the error

Comment: Hey @GauravGupta did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Bengala bundle update worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`alias_method_chain` has been deprecated in rails 5. Try updating the `activeadmin` gem using `bundle update activeadmin`